# Issue with ElasticSearch 8.4 query

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi i have recently been busy reworking our old and outdated ES now um running 8.4 and im trying to create a similar query to what i had in the old one. But i have a hard time finding examples or the right documentation

**This is an example what we had on version 1.7:**
I have tried te exact same in 8.4 now

```
{
  "index": "vehicles",
  "type": "vehicle",
  "body": {
    "from": "0",
    "size": 30,
    "query": {
      "filtered": {
        "query": { "match_all": [] },
        "filter": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    [
                      { "term": { "make.untouched": "IVECO" } },
                      { "term": { "make.untouched": "VOLKSWAGEN" } }
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [[{ "term": { "type_serie.untouched": "DAILY" } }]]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [[{ "term": { "filters.header.camper": "true" } }]]
                }
              },
              { "range": { "days_sold": { "gte": 0, "lt": 2 } } },
              { "range": { "days_on_stock": { "gte": 3 } } },
              { "range": { "price": { "gt": 0 } } },
              { "range": { "price_trader": { "gt": 0 } } },
              { "term": { "show_in_search": true } }
            ],
            "must_not": [
              { "term": { "offer_code": "z" } },
              { "term": { "stockingtype": "a" } },
              { "term": { "stockingtype": "v" } },
              { "term": { "stockingtype": "z" } },
              { "term": { "stockingtype": "p" } }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "sort": [
      { "_score": "desc" },
      { "days_on_stock": "asc" },
      { "price": "asc" }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to know what's not working anymore and which previous version you had.

Comment: I think your double arrays `[[ ... ]]` might be an issue though, you only need one level `[ ... ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have double arrays and that's the issue (older versions were more permissive):

```
              "should": [
 remove this -->[
                  { "term": { "make.untouched": "IVECO" } },
                  { "term": { "make.untouched": "VOLKSWAGEN" } }
 remove this -->]
              ]
```

Same here

```
                     same here                                       same here
          {              |                                              |
            "bool": {    v                                              v
              "should": [[{ "term": { "type_serie.untouched": "DAILY" } }]]
            }
          },
          {
            "bool": {
              "should": [[{ "term": { "filters.header.camper": "true" } }]]
            }
          },
```